# how to get the f-statistic,p-value out of NonLinearModel in MATLAB 2013a

Tags: matlab

I use mdl=NonLinearModel.fit to fit a non-linear model. 
How can I get the F-statistic and p-value from the result (line: "F-statistic vs. constant model")?

Example code:

```
load carsmall
 X = Weight;
 y = MPG;
 modelfun = 'y ~ b1 + b2*exp(-b3*x/1000)';
 beta0 = [1 1 1];
 mdl=NonLinearModel.fit(X,y,modelfun,beta0)
```

which produces the following:

```
mdl =
Nonlinear regression model:
    y ~ b1 + b2*exp( - b3*x/1000)
Estimated Coefficients:
          Estimate      SE        tStat        pValue  
          ________    _______    ________    __________
    b1    -17.725      31.321    -0.56594       0.57283
    b2     77.862      21.332      3.6499    0.00043735
    b3    0.21775     0.17176      1.2677       0.20814
Number of observations: 94, Error degrees of freedom: 91
Root Mean Squared Error: 4.12
R-Squared: 0.743,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.738
F-statistic vs. constant model: 132, p-value = 1.34e-27
```

Comment: Look here:
http://mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinearmodel.coeftest.html#zmw57dd0e119263
However, when I do `[p,F] = coefTest(mdl)` in your example, I get different p- and F-values than reported when you display the model. Also, `fTest(mdl)` isn't allowed, although the `NonLinearModel` class has an `fTest` method. I guess it is protected or inaccessible.
To calculate it manually using the formula you see in the linked page, you need to know v (C, H and beta-hat in the formula are known). I don't know how to calculate v.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for going through these!
I tried similar things to your suggestions and couldn't find a solution as well..
I think I could copy the fTest and all private methods that it calls to another function, but I will have to copy quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need `[Fstat,pval]=fTest(mdl);`
However this requires you to change permissions to `public` in a number of scripts. I just ran MATLAB as root and manually changed every permission to public in all files that were returning errors until I could actually get what I needed. It seems to work but there is probably a better way to do it.